# Pandas read csv file error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, encoding

I would like to open csv data but keep getting the same error, what can I do to succesfully open csv files using Python?

```
#Reading in the files
import pandas as pd
data1 = pd.read_csv("data1.csv")
```

> **UnicodeDecodeError**: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`byte 0xff in position 0` means that your `.csv` is probably encoded in [*utf-16*](https://perl.mines-albi.fr/perl5.8.5/5.8.5/pod/perlunicode.html).

Try this :

```
data1 = pd.read_csv("data1.csv", encoding="utf-16")
```

Comment: How can you tell that `byte 0xff in position 0 means...  utf-16."?  I'm getting a similar error and was hoping to know how you go about determining the encoding based on the byte value.

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer and linked a great material about BOMs and encodings.