# I can not read a CSV file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I could not read a CSV file with jupyter notebook
my code is

```
dk = pd.read_csv('male_playersK.csv')
```

the error message is

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 14: invalid continuation byte

i have tried  the following code  but still did not work

```
dk = pd.read_csv(r'male_playersK.csv')
```

and

```
dk = pd.read_csv('male_playersK.csv',  encoding='unicode_escape')
```

Comment: Why would you think using a raw string for the filename would make any difference? You have no backslash characters in the name.

Comment: You need to find out what encoding was actually used when creating the file, and use that in the `encoding` option.

Comment: There are a lot of posts already covering this that you need to determine the encoding and then set that in your `pd.read_csv()` call properly, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73948137/8508004) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18172249/8508004), for examples. You have trying to set the encoding in your second code block, but aren't apparently setting the correct encoding yet. Did you already try `encoding="latin1"`? You could try [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66062975/8508004) that steps through them and finds you maybe the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Following solution should help you as a quick patch. To solve it properly you need to find the encoding used to save the file, as suggested in the comments to the question.

However, on many occasions most of the characters in the csv can be successfully decoded with utf-8 and only a few are the troublemakers. If you are willing to accept loss of characters utf-8 can't accept and using pandas **v1.3** and above, you can do

```
dk = pd.read_csv('male_playersK.csv', encoding_errors='ignore')
```

You can also use `encoding_errors='replace'` to see which characters were lost